# text align justify doesn't work on floating element

Tags: php, css

I am trying to aligned justify the div block. It works fine if I do that statically.

```css
ul {
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  text-align:justify;
  border:solid thin #000;
  padding:0;
}

ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:26%;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  padding:0;
}

ul::after{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>  
  <li></li>  
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

However, since the data I have is from `php foreach`, it doesn't work, because the tag element is floating with no white space.

```css
    ul {
      width:500px;
      display:block;
      text-align:justify;
      border:solid thin #000;
      padding:0;
    }

    ul li{
      display:inline-block;
      width:26%;
      height:150px;
      background:red;
      padding:0;
    }

    ul::after{
      content:"";
      width:100%;
      display:inline-block
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ul>
```

I may be able to handle this with the style of how I fetching data in `php` like this:

```
  foreach ($data as $list): ?>
```

However, sometime the `:` sign can confuse the linux command when I run the php with linux script command.

Can anybody help me how to solve this with css only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the article [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), I think you could resolve this only with **CSS Flexbox**.

https://jsfiddle.net/1dduLyy0/2/

```
ul {
  width:500px;  
  text-align:justify;
  border:solid thin #000;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul li{
  display:flex;
  width:26%;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  padding:0;
}

ul::after{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block
}
```

Hope this is accurate to your problem.

Good Luck'

**EDIT:**
https://jsfiddle.net/1dduLyy0/3/

To make the 3 `li` fit to the whole row.

```
ul li{
  width: calc(100%/3);
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Is it only me or anybody else see that it doesn't align justify the element?

Comment: I supposed you are browsing on *Firefox*. Just checked on it, this doesn't work indeed, I'm working on it.

Comment: Having a look around with the other browsers, but should be fine now.

Comment: I will accept this answer if you can remove the white space inside the ul which look like `padding`

Comment: You mean like https://jsfiddle.net/1dduLyy0/3/ ? The was here because your `li` elements have a `26%` width, so only **3** elements can fit in a row.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood what you were looking for. But as far as you found the solution, it's fine. : )

Answer (score 1):

can't you just do something like:

```
foreach ($data as $list){
$result = "<li class='testClass'>" . $list . "</li>";
}

echo $result;
```

I don't really understand if list is the full list or just the values you actually want to print as list in the html tho.

**EDIT**

If you don't mind the div to have the same height -> http://jsfiddle.net/5o9u644u/

If you want them to keep the same height -> http://jsfiddle.net/rc3cfgo5/

Comment: actually they were there just for debugging purpose that I echoed blank "<li></li>; just to find out what the real problem of that css is. Yes, i think your answer will solve the problem. But, I am still hoping that the css can solve this problem.

Comment: so you want a 3 column div with your data, right? if yes, i can edit my answer to fix the css as well

Comment: yes, `the column is three` Only the number of `</li> is unpredictable, it based on the number from mysql query result.